Suppose $v_1,v_2,\dots, v_m$ is linearly independent in $V$and $w\in V$ prove that $dim(span(v_1+w,v_2+w,\dots v_m+w)) \geq m-1$
Suppose $v_1,v_2,\dots, v_m$ is linearly independent in $V$and $w\in V$ prove that $dim(span(v_1+w,v_2+w,\dots v_m+w)) \geq 1$
Here's my working
We split this into two cases, in the first case $w=0$. In which case $dim(span (v_1,v_2,\dots, v_m))$ is $m$ by definition. By the ordering of the naturals, $m>m-1$
We now examine $dim(span(v_1+w, v_2+w ,  \dots, v_m+w))$. As $v \in V$, we now have two more cases
. Case 1: $w \notin span(v_1,v_2,\dots, v_m)$ . In this case $v_1+w, v_2+w, \dots, v_m+w$ is also linearly independent . This can be proven by contradiction, as follows. If they weren't linearly independent, it follows that $av_1+bv_2 + \dots + a_mv_m = -(a_1+a_2 + \dots + a_m)w $ .it follows that some $\sum_{I=1}^{k} a_iv_i=(a_1+a_2+ \dots + a_m)w$. But this implies $w$ lies in the span of $v_1,v_2, \dots, v_m)$, which is a contradiction, thus, the vectors  are linearly independent, which gives us this conclusion:: This list of m vectors is linearly independent. Thus the dimension of the space is $m$.
We now assume  that $w \in span(v_1,v_2, \dots, v_m)$. Thus $w=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots + a_mv_m$. We now attempt to check if $ v_1+w, v_2+w,\dots, v_m+w$ is linearly independent
$$b_1(v_1+w)+b_2(v_1+w)+ \dots+ b_m(v_m+w)=0$$. From this it follows that $b_1v_1+b_2v_2+ \dots b_nv_n = -(b_1w1+b_2w+ \dots + b_mw)$$.
That is $$b_1v_1+b_2v_2+ \dots + b_nv_n=-(b_1(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+ \dots + a_mv_m)+b_2(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+ \dots + a_mv_m) + \dots + b_m(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+ \dots + a_mv_m)$$.
From this it follows that $$ b_1v_1+b_2v_2+ \dots + b_nv_n+(b_1(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+ \dots + a_mv_m)+b_2(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+ \dots + a_mv_m) + \dots + b_m(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+ \dots + a_mv_m)=0$$.
Regrouping this we get
$$(b_1+b_1a_1+b_2a_1+\dots +b_ma_1)v_1+(b_1a_2+b_2+b_2a_2+ \dots b_ma_2)v_2 + \dots+ (b_m+b_1a_m+b_2a_m+ \dots b_ma_m)v_m $$
Equating all the equations to zero and solving we get
\begin{pmatrix}
1+a_1 & a_1 & \cdots & a_1 \\
a_2+1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_m+1 & a_m & \cdots & a_m
\end{pmatrix}
Nots sure what to do beyond this,I'd appreciate any hints.
While column reduction's result is pretty easy to see here, I don't see how that helps.
I'm of the opinion that row reduction doesn't help here in anyway whatsoever.

Maybe it is easier to prove that $\text{dim}(\text{span}(v_1+w, \ldots, v_m+w)) \ne 0$? And I guess we need $m \ge 2$.

Ooops, typo in the title

If $m>1$ then this is trivial. If $m=1$ then choosing $w=-v_1$ shows that it is false.

You should re-edit the top line of your post. MEanwhile yes it is on the person writing the question to be clear.

Isn't it obvious by row operations (when vectors are written in rows)?

Let the subspace $U = \text{span}(v_{1}+w, v_{2}+w, \dots, v_{m}+w)$.
We have to prove that dimension of subspace is greater than $m-1$. If by doing something, I can give you list of $m-1$ independet vectors in that subspace, then you can for sure say that dimension is greater than or equal to $m-1$.
If you observe we were given $v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{m}$ are independent. By this I construct the following list of vectors $L = (v_{1}-v_{2},v_{2}-v_{3},\dots,v_{m-1}-v_{m})$. Let's check if this list is independent. Consider
\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}c_{i}(v_{i} - v_{i+1}) = 0
\end{aligned}\\
&\begin{aligned}
\implies c_{1}v_{1} + (c_{2}-c_{1})v_{2} + \dots - c_{m-1}v_{m} = 0
\end{aligned}\\
\end{align*}
But we know that $(v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{m})$ are independent which means $c_{1} = 0, c_{2} = c_{1}, \dots, c_{m-1} = 0$ which says that list $L$ is independent. Also each vector in $L$ belongs to $U$.
So by using the fact dimension is greater than or equal to length of independent vectors I can say $\dim U \geq m - 1$.

Some more explanation as to why your list is independent would be nice.

I will add it. Thanks

Thank you for revising!

If $w \notin \operatorname{sp} \{ v_k\}$ and $\sum_k \alpha_k (v_k+w) = 0$, then $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k + (\sum_k \alpha_k) w = 0$. We see that $ (\sum_k \alpha_k) = 0$ (otherwise a quick contradiction) and hence $\alpha_k = 0$. Hence $\dim \operatorname{sp} \{ v_k+w\} = m$.
If $w=0$ the result is trivial.
If $w \in \operatorname{sp} \{ v_k\}\setminus \{0\}$ then $w=\sum_k \beta_k v_k$ for some $\beta_k$. We can assume that $\beta_1 \neq 0$. Then
$\dim \operatorname{sp} \{ v_k+w\}_{k>1} = m-1$. To see this, suppose
$\sum_{k>1} \alpha_k (v_k+w) = \sum_{k>1} \alpha_k v_k + (\sum_{k>1} \alpha_k )(\beta_1 v_1+  \sum_{k>1} \beta_k v_k) = 0$. We must have $(\sum_{k>1} \alpha_k ) = 0$ and hence $\alpha_k = 0$. In particular, the $v_k+w$, $k>1$ are linearly independent.

By "row-operations',
$$\text{span}(v_{1}+w, v_{2}+w, \dots, v_{m}+w)\\
=\text{span}(v_{1}+w, v_{2}-v_1, \dots, v_{m}-v_1)\\
\supseteq 
\text{span}(v_{2}-v_1, \dots, v_{m}-v_1).\tag1$$
On the other hand,
$$\text{span}(v_{2}-v_1, \dots, v_{m}-v_1)+\text{span}(v_1)=
\text{span}(v_1, \dots, v_{m})
$$
Therefore,
$$\dim\text{span}(v_{2}-v_1, \dots, v_{m}-v_1)=m-1$$
and by $(1)$
$$\dim\text{span}(v_{1}+w, v_{2}+w, \dots, v_{m}+w)\geq m-1.
$$

Suppose that $\boldsymbol{w}\in\text{Span}\{\boldsymbol{v}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_m\}$, then there exist some coefficients $w_1,\dots,w_m$ in the base field such that $\boldsymbol{w}=\sum_{i=1}^mw_i\boldsymbol{v}_i$. Now, consider the space $\text{Span}\{\boldsymbol{v}_1+\boldsymbol{w},\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_m+\boldsymbol{w}\}$. Then:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{u}_j=\boldsymbol{v}_j+\boldsymbol{w}=\boldsymbol{v}_j+\sum_{i=1}^mw_i\boldsymbol{v}_i=\sum_{i=1}^m\delta_{ij}\boldsymbol{v}_i+\sum_{i=1}^mw_i\boldsymbol{v}_i=\sum_{i=1}^m(w_i+\delta_{ij})\boldsymbol{v}_i=\sum_{i=1}^mA_{ij}\boldsymbol{v}_i.
\end{equation}
Following your approach, define the matrix $A=(A_{ij})$, namely:
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1+w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & \cdots & w_m \\
w_1 & 1+w_2 & w_3 & \cdots & w_m \\
w_1 & w_2 & 1+w_3 & \cdots & w_m \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & \cdots & 1+w_m
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
It should be clear that $m\geq\text{Rank}(A)\geq m-1$, indeed, by doing elementary matrix operations, $A$ can be put in the following form:
\begin{equation}
\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -1\\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4 & \cdots & w_{m-1} & w_m
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Clearly, this shows that $m\geq\text{dim}\text{Span}\{\boldsymbol{u}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{u}_m\}\geq m-1$.
